# How to embed Python list as it is in Django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

There is a Django template in my web app which has a JavaScript section in it.

#### chart.html

```
{% block footer_javascript_section %}<script type="text/javascript" >
g = new Dygraph(

// containing div
document.getElementById("graphdiv"),

// CSV or path to a CSV file.
"{{ biogas_plant_str }}",

{width: 1000,
height: 400,
labels: {{biogas_plant_list}} }  /*  <---- THIS list */ 
);
</script> 
{% endblock footer_javascript_section %}
```

I've passed in a Python list in the context of the `chart` view function.The list is referred by `biogas_plant_list`.

### The issue

I need to embed the Python list **as it is**, without splitting or iterating over it. Other questions similar to this one, required the list to be handled in some way. A list has to be output after substitution.
`['s1','s2']`
However template substitutes the HTML character entities instead of the actual decoded characters. How to turn it off?

`[&#39;&quot;25.7\\n&quot;&#39;, &#39;&quot;26.3\\n&quot;&#39; ]`

Comment: Can we simmply not  join the list and pass it as a String variable to the template.

Comment: I suppose it could be done.Might have to split it again when passing it the JS constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/), Django templates auto-escape quotes characters and such by default.

> **autoescape**¶
>
> Controls the current auto-escaping behavior. This tag takes either on or off as an argument and that determines whether auto-escaping is in effect inside the block. The block is closed with an endautoescape ending tag.

```
 {% autoescape off %}
labels: {{biogas_plant_list}} }
{% endautoescape %}
```